# Correctly order the hierarchy of custom taxonomy when displaying terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy

On my page I am displaying the custom taxonomy terms relevant to a post. For example a post may have a heirachy of:

```
Filmmaking -> Production -> Cinematogrpahy
```

To do this I am using the below code in my `content-child` page

```
<?php
    /*Retrieve Category Name */ 
        if(get_the_terms($post->ID, 'kernal_category', true)) {
            // Create an empty array

            $kernal_category = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'kernal_category', true);

            $categories = [];

            // Save each category to the array
            foreach ($kernal_category as $category) {

            $categories[] = $category->name;
            }

            // Now output with implode
                        echo implode(' > ', $categories);
            }
    ?>
```

My problem is that when these terms are displayed they are not following the correct hierachy. Using the example above my post is actually displayed as follows: `Cinematography -> Production -> Filmmaking`.

I have already checked and the primary for this taxonomy is set correctly i.e. the Primary for *Cinematography* is *Filmmaking*

How do I display them hierarchically?

Update: It appears to affect taxonomies with more than a Primary and Secondary term. All posts with just primary and secondary are displaying correctly.

Comment: There's an important distinction that needs to be known to answer this question, depending on how your understand terms to work. Did you check Cinematography? Or did you check all 3 terms Cinematography Production and Film making? If it's the first one, then a really simple solution can be written as the answer, but if it's the second one... the answer will have to be more complex due to the misunderstanding. Finally, are all terms guaranteed to be in a parent/child/grandchild/etc relationship? Is this an attempt to build breadcrumbs?

Comment: @TomJNowell apologies for the omission. I have ticked all 3, Filmmaking, Production, Cinematography.  And yes all cases will be parent/child/grandchild. I will never for example be clicking 2 parent, or 2 child terms for one post. It is a breadcrumb, it is to let a user know how deep into a particular taxonomy the post they are viewing is.

Comment: Ah, that complicates things. For future reference, you only need to assign the grandchild term, ticking the parent terms is unnecessary. It's a bit like saying something is a sweater, then explicitly stating that it is also an item of clothing ( where clothing is the parent term ), it's just generally understood that sweaters are clothing, terms are inclusive and contain all the things assigned to their child terms too unless otherwise stated

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did however try this and when displaying the breadcrumb all that is shown now is the grandchild term.  Is there though now an easy way of coding the function to show the parent terms? I am only using test data so far.

Comment: You  have  to manually  account for them, as I said, the solution for either circumstance is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a term and all its parents/ancestors, you can do the following:

```php
function display_term_parents( \WP_Term $starting_term ) {
    $terms = [];
    $term = $starting_term;
    while ( !is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
        $terms[] = $term->name;
        $term = get_term( $term->parent, 'kernal_category' );
    }
    $terms = array_reverse( $terms );
    echo implode(' > ', $terms );
}
```

Where `$starting_term` is the term you want to show the ancestors/parents for.

This can be done for each term ( or just the first term ) that a post has, assuming that you've only checked the term you want, but not all of its parents too

Comment: Thanks for your patience but I think I'm missing something obvious. For the starting term I'm trying to feed it using ```get_the_terms($post->ID, 'kernal_category', true)``` however nothing is displayed. When I ```var_dump( $term)``` I get NULL. What is the correct format I need to have the $term value in?

Comment: This isn't copy pasta code, you need a term to start with, since you already have code that lists all the terms a post has, you already have all the pieces you need. The starting term is the term you're wanting to show the rest of the breadcrumb for, aka the one you're trying to show the parent terms for, aka `Cinematogrpahy` in your original example. I also spotted a mistake I made, but again you need to get `$starting_term` from somewhere,  it can't be pulled from thin air. I've also wrapped it in a function to  make it a bit easier

Comment: Thanks for the clean up. I did realise that 'Cinematography' should be the term, I just can't figure out how to give that to the function you've created. It seems like the ```$starting_term``` parameter needs to be an object - but if I send the value from ```$kernal_category``` which is retrieved using ```get_the_terms``` nothing is displayed. Having debugged it seems to not  recognise a ```term_id != 0``` and thus the while loop never triggers. I have also tried using different functions to retrieve the term in a different format with no luck.

Comment: try it now, I changed the exit  condition

Comment: No luck, I'm now getting this error -  ```Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 536870920 bytes) ```. I'm not just copying and pasting, I've been trying to figure out where this is going wrong but I'm fairly inexperienced and drawing a blank.

Comment: It sounds like it never exits the loop, I realised I madea nother mistake in there

Comment: This still wasn't working but I've finally found a fix. I had to change it to ```$term = $starting_term[0]```. Without this ```$terms[] = $term->name;``` was simply returning `NULL`. It now works - does this make sense? If so I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Sounds like you were passing an array of terms into the function, not a term, I've added a typehint to enforce that, you should see a PHP fatal error if you try to use it incorrectly now about passing an array in where there should be a term